# How to call stored procedures in MVC4 application with Ado.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures, ado.net

I would like to know how to call stored procedures in MVC4 application using Ado.net and the database tables does not contain primary key. I am not using Entity framework. 
Any approaches and suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks and Regards,
Steven

Comment: Start with sqlcommand. Internet is full of examples using ado.

Comment: I think you will have problems with this.  These frameworks do really like their primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

Depending if the sp is returning data or not, you might change the way you execute it:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("pr_stored_proc", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", 123);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
               //get data
        }

    }
}
```

If it does not return data (Update for example) then just don't use the reader, and just execute it using `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`